# Apache not respecting MinSpareServer and MinSpareServer in WHM/Cpanel Apache configuration

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7, load-testing

I am using Apache 2.4 and event MPM on my centos server with WHM control panel.

I have set  `MinSpareServers` to 50 and `MaxSparServers` to 55 in    of 
Global Configuration of the WHM Apache configuration.

Yet, in Apache status, I see only 10-15 processes of Apache.
[image: screenshot of the apapceh status page]

Due to which most of my apache slots are  showing empty/dot "." in the scorecard.

Here is my apache scorecard :

**RR_R__R__RR__RRR______RW__R_____RR_R_____R______RRWRWRR__RRR_R
RRRRRRR_R_R.....................................................
......................__R___RR__R__________R__R.................
........_RRR___RW________________...............................
................................................................
.......................................................R_R_RR_**
__________R__R_R.........................RRRRRR_RRRWRWRRRRRRRRRR
RR..............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...................................RRRRW_RRRRRWRRRRRRRRRRRRR....
.....................RRRRRRRRRRRWRRRRRRRRR_WRWRRRWRRRRR_RWRRRRRR
RRRRRRR.........................RRRRRRRWR_RRRRRRRRRRR_RRR.......
................................................................
......................................................RRRRRRRRRR
RR_WWRRWRRRRRRR........................._RR_RRRR_RRRRRR_RR_RRR_R
R__RRRRRRRRRR_R_RRRRRR__RR......................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
........

Note : If I set `StartServer` to 50 and restart my server, 50 processes are started but something kills and brings back the count to 10-15.

Am I missing something? Should not the number of apache processes running be between the values defined by  MaxSpareServers and MinSpareServers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the `MinSpareServers` and `MaxSpareServers` directives are only relevant in the context of the [**prefork** MPM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html).

For the [**event** MPM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html) you should be looking at `MaxRequestWorkers`, 
`MaxSpareThreads` and 
`MinSpareThreads`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! this is true, your hint helped me solve the issue